# Do snapshots only work with AR turned on?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have the Research Task to "Take a Snapshot of a Dratini", as part of the "Jumpstart Research" challenge.

I found a Dratini, and took a photo (using the camera icon in the capture minigame screen), but the task did not complete. However, I do not use the AR feature (that is, I do not open my camera and view the Pokémon through my phone's camera).

Does this Task require me to use my camera to view the Pokémon and take the photo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you have to take a snapshot using your phones camera, it has to be of a captured Pokemon.  It doesn't, however, require you to use AR+ which is useful.  From the article linked below:

> Taking a snapshot of a Dratini is a bit more tricky as you have to catch a Dratini first. **When you've caught one, just click on the camera icon** at the top of the screen to take a snapshot of it. Or if you don't want to go out and catch a new Pokemon and already have a Dratini, select it in your Pokemon list and click the camera icon at the top right-hand corner. **The little fella will appear in AR**, and then you just tap the camera icon again to take a snapshot of it.

Sources: I've been playing the game for years and related articles available online.

[Jump Start Research](https://www.gamesradar.com/uk/pokemon-go-jump-start-research/)

As a side note from what I entered in the comments, the Snap Shot feature is the only current way (as of September 2019) to obtain a Smeargle.  It will randomly photo bomb your picture (appearing in the bottom corner) and then be catch-able in the game world.

Comment: I followed your instructions. I have taken a pic of a dratini I have in AR mode and it doesn’t count it. It also won’t count the snapshot I take with my buddy dratini.

Comment: @GamerMEK There's currently a bug with snapshots.

Comment: @GamerMEK there is a bug causing Snapshots not to register on iOS devices. You'll have to use an android or wait for a fix.